# Machine learning benchmark test for raspberry pi 4

Tags: machine-learning

I know of three ai benchmarks. One I know works on raspberry pi. I need to do benchmarks for inference tests on machine learning. I am not doing training. I cannot use [ai-benchmark](http://ai-benchmark.com/) for this test per the requirements. The other benchmarks I know are [aibench](http://www.benchcouncil.org/AIBench/index.html) and [mlperf](https://mlperf.org/). AIBench does not support IoT yet, and MLPerf cannot be compared to non MLPerf results. I am doing research that compares different hardware and it is not using MLPerf. What are some other benchmarks I can use for this?